# How can i display TEXT associated with a given link as Hyperlink in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm currently coding my first application in java and I have this class that updates the database on server startup for JSP page through servlet. The problem is, what is updated to the database are links to articles and they are displayed in JSP as is in the database. What I want displayed in JSP is the Headlines/Text of those articles as Hyperlinks to the articles.

Comment: It will be better to post here the structure of data you are storing, and the piece of JSP where you are trying to display it.

Comment: Thanks  sanastasiiadis. I have this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026313/how-can-i-display-text-associated-with-a-given-link-as-hyperlink-in-jsp/40026512#40026512   but i want this displayed as hyperlink in JSP: How can i display TEXT associated with a given link as Hyperlink in JSP?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this like you would normally do with plain HTML but with JSP Expression Language to display.

`<a href="${object.linkUrl}">${object.headline}</a>`

Assuming object has linkUrl and headline as properties.
If you do not have headline in your object or in your database, you need to hard code the headline

`<a href="${object.linkUrl}">headline</a>`

Your object should be in one of the four scope already: `page, request, session,application.`

Comment: I'm trying this now minjun.Y thanks. I'll get back to you.